# Creating an action for moving layers on the x axis to the widest width of a selected layer?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I want to make a variable action that separates a series of layers based on the widest width of one of those selected layers. 4 sprites are 100, 100, 100, 200 pixels wide. It'd separate the layers all by 200 pixels on the x axis and make the image 800 pixels wide total.

I am able to do this easily if all layers are the same but cannot make it work with variability. Not sure if there are any photoshop wizards willing to lend me their time to make a script but it would be extremely helpful!

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this. This presumes that there're no groups, no Background layer, layers are normal layers and all document layers are used. Before-after (largest was 150px):

[image]

If you don't need them to change `Y` position, change `0 - layersInfo[i].top` to `0` on line 13.

```
function main()
{
    var doc = activeDocument,
        layers = doc.layers, //getting all top layers
        layersInfo = getInfo().reverse(), //getting layers info and reversing the array because DOM indexes are different order than AM indexes
        elWidth = getWidestElement(layersInfo); // getting widest element

    doc.resizeCanvas(elWidth * layers.length, doc.height.as("px"), AnchorPosition.TOPLEFT); // resizing canvas size to new width: widest element * number of elements

    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) // for every top layer...
    {
        doc.activeLayer = layers[i]; // selecting the layer
        layers[i].translate(i * elWidth - layersInfo[i].left, 0 - layersInfo[i].top) // moving it to top left corner of each block
    }

    function getInfo()
    {
        var layers = 1,
            lyrs = [];
        while (true)
        {
            ref = new ActionReference();
            ref.putIndex(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), layers);
            try
            {
                var desc = executeActionGet(ref);
            }
            catch (err)
            {
                break;
            }

            var lyr = {},
                bounds = desc.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID("bounds"));;

            lyr.top = bounds.getDouble(stringIDToTypeID("top"));
            lyr.left = bounds.getDouble(stringIDToTypeID("left"));
            lyr.width = bounds.getDouble(stringIDToTypeID("width"));

            lyrs.push(lyr)
            layers++;
        }
        return lyrs
    }; // end of getInfo()

    function getWidestElement(layers)
    {
        var curWidth = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++)
        {
            if (layers[i].width > curWidth) curWidth = layers[i].width;
        }
        return curWidth
    }; // end of getWidestElement()


}

var curUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;
try
{
    app.activeDocument.suspendHistory("temp", "main()");
}
catch (e)
{
    alert(e + '\nLine: ' + e.line)
}
app.preferences.rulerUnits = curUnits;
```